# Is it possible to program NodeJs where you can delete automatically the trash bin or recycle bin of a user?

Tags: node.js, windows, macos

Is it possible to access the trashbin or recycle bin and delete its contents or items using Nodejs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can permanently delete files using unlink() method from "fs" module. As far as I know, the runtime doesn't have any API to access the trash bin and operate on it, so you have to go around the problem, restore files, then use fs.unlink() on the files. That's the only legitimate way to do this.

Comment: you mean i cannot go through the path of where the trash bin is located and delete the files from there?

Comment: Sadly, yes. Unless you interfere with system files, you can't just go to the recycle bin path and remove them with node.js method, because files are hidden and the folder attributes needed for your goal are protected from toggling.